# ExecuteSqlRaw with PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql

I have a query.

When I run the function, I get the error "42P01: relation "StudentsAndClasses" does not exist' postgresql".

But it works in Postgresql query editor.

```
C#

public void DeleteFromClass(int StudentId, int ClassId)
    {
        using var dbContext = new DatabaseContext();
        var cmd = @"DELETE FROM StudentsAndClasses WHERE StudentId=@p0 And ClassId=@p1";
        dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(cmd, StudentId, ClassId);
    }

delete query in postgresql

    DELETE FROM public."StudentsAndClasses" WHERE <condition>;
```

Comment: var cmd = @"DELETE FROM public.StudentsAndClasses WHERE StudentId=@p0 And ClassId=@p1";

Comment: its not working. error: Npgsql.PostgresException: '42P01: relation "public.studentsandclasses " does not exist'

Comment: Try adding the quotes (you need to double them in C#) `var cmd = @"DELETE FROM public.""StudentsAndClasses"" WHERE ""StudentId""=@p0 And ""ClassId""=@p1";`

Answer (score 0):

In Postgresql object identifiers that are not in double quotes are folded to lower case and columns that are not created with double quotes are also folded to lower case. So there is a possibility that your StudentId and ClassId as well as the table name have wrong casing when the command is executed against the db.  As you can see in the error message relation public.studentsandclasses (all lower case) is not the same as your command.

Comment: i try @"delete from public.studentsandclasses where StudentId=@p0 And ClassId=@p1"; but i still get error. I also removed the public prefix from the beginning of the table and ran it again, I got the same error.

Comment: You still have capital characaters in Studentid and Classid.

Comment: I tried but it still didn't work @"delete from public.studentsandclasses where studentid=@p0 and classid=@p1";  I also removed the prefix and ran it again @"delete from studentsandclasses where studentid=@p0 and classid=@p1";